error when trying to install nvidia drivers on debian 12 'Bookworm'
when i try to install nvidia-driver using sudo apt install nvidia-driver it puts out errors
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia : Depends: xorg-video-abi-24 or
                                      xorg-video-abi-23 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-8 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-6.0 but it is not installable
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (< 2:1.20.99) but 2:21.1.12-1 is to be installed
                             Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 418) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Im new to linux and cant seem to fix the issue.
apt policy -
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam i386 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=stable,l=Steam launcher,c=steam,b=i386
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable/steam amd64 Packages
     release o=Valve Software LLC,n=stable,l=Steam launcher,c=steam,b=amd64
     origin repo.steampowered.com
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/non-free-firmware i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/non-free i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/non-free amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=unstable,n=sid,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free,b=i386
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=i386
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib i386 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main i386 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release v=10.13,o=Debian,a=oldoldstable,n=buster,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bookworm-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/non-free-firmware i386 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free-firmware,b=i386
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bookworm-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free-firmware i386 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/non-free-firmware amd64 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=non-free-firmware,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main i386 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=main,b=i386
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages
     release v=12.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bookworm,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org


Your system seems to have been partially upgraded to Debian testing. Could you [edit] your question to show the output of apt policy?

updated it and posted.
